# Can I use Sharepoint 2013 Standard license in trial version Sharepoint 2010 w/ Ent CAL

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I installed Sharepoint 2010 with Enterprise Client Access License
My license is Sharepoint 2013 Standard
but I get a message
"The product key could not be validated. Check the error for Log details"
Will my license key work?

Comment: Could you please clairfy the question...you said you have SP 2010 Installed with Enterprise cal and in the same farm you want to install SP2013....OR you trying to upgrade the Sp2010 to SP 2013?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate SharePoint 2010, you need to use the key for SP2010 trial.

According to microsoft [download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16631), the keys are:

Enterprise: VK7BD-VBKWR-6FHD9-Q3HM9-6PKMX

Standard: PTTCF-PCY26-D9V8F-8JF8B-XH8JP

and another two type of keys listed at website.